# ¿Pasar datos de un datagrid a otro formulario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Tengo dos formulario (A-B) en el formulario B tengo un datagrid cargado desde la BD , los cuales selecciono y paso al formulario A.

Este es el codigo del fomulario A, con el que llamoa l formulario B

```
 Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
```

Este es el codigo del Formulario B con el que mando los datos

```html
            Form1 frm = new Form1();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() ==
                    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                {
                    frm.codigofactura.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    frm.cliente.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    frm.proveedor.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    frm.total.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                    int index = frm.tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
                    frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
                    frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
                    frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
                    frm.tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = row.Cells[8].Value;
                }

            }

            frm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
```

El codigo me funciona.. pero el problema que tengo es que me abre varios formularios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que los datos me los devuelva al mismo formulario y no me abra otro formulario

Comment: Elimina las lineas donde creas el formulario de tipo **Form1 frm = new Form1();** y donde haces el **frm.ShowDialog();**. No es necesario. El close es correcto. Y puedes acceder a los datos del form2 después de cerrarlo, pues existe la instancia al volver después del _close()_ que haces en la primera parte.

Comment: si quito el  **Form1**  ¿como paso los datos del  **Form2**  al  **Form1** ?

Comment: Lo que quitas es el repetir abrir el Form1 desde el Form2, ya que el Form2 lo creas desde el Form1, eso te crea un ciclo que te crea repetidas veces esos formularios de forma ciclica...

Comment: Preguntas como esta, hay varias el ultimo mes. Busca en las preguntas del sitio y encontraras info similar a la respuesta que necesitas

Comment: @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga ya lo quite ¿pero como paso los datos?

Comment: @RamiroBarone si he estado buscando pero hasta ahora no he encontrado

Comment: después del ShowDialog, puedes acceder a todos los elementos desde la variable frm.  Eso es porque no vuelves de esa función hasta que se cierra el formulario dibujado, y al volver, no se destruye todavía.

Comment: @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga me podrías dar un ejemplo.. te lo agradecería

Comment: @Fernandez, Ahora te pongo uno basado en tu propio código, re-ordenando simplemente tu código... falta mucho código para probarlo, pero debería funcionar... En unos minutos lo tienes...

Comment: ok. te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te pongo un ejemplo para "ilustrar" lo comentado anteriormente. Me basaré en tu propio código y tu estructura inicial:

> Este es el código del formulario A, con el que llamo al formulario B

```
 Form2 frm = new Form2();
 frm.ShowDialog();

 /* Accedemos a los datos del segundo formulario usando el objeto frm */
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in frm.dataGridView1.Rows) 
 {
     if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
     {
         /* Actualizamos los objetos del Formulario A con los datos recuperados del Form2  */
         codigofactura.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
         cliente.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
         proveedor.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
         total.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

         int index = tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
         tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
         tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
         tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
         tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = row.Cells[8].Value;
      }
 }
```

Espero que te sea útil el ejemplo.

Comment: me arroja este error 'No se pueden agregar filas mediante programación a la colección de filas de DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado a datos.'
`

Comment: Te hago otra pregunta los datos yo los pasaba por un evento click en ese evento no agrego nada?

Comment: Esa es la "parte" que me temía que no veía del código ya realizado... Supongo usas un **BindingSource** enlazado al **DataSource** de tu **GridView** (o tal vez de un **GridControl**, dependiendo del _framework_ usado)... Si ese es el caso, entonces deberías hacer los **add** directamente en el **BindingSource**

Comment: y como hago eso ?

Comment: Una cosa, fijate que tal vez no viste edité la linea del **int index = tblarticulo.Rows.Add();**  (quité el frm.  justo unos segundos después de publicar la respuesta, ese también puede ser la razón del problema y no lo has visto seguramente)

Comment: Si quieres utilizar el **BindingSource** cambia el objeto **tblarticulo** por el nombre del objeto **BindingSource** que usas en el **GridView**... Luego el visualizador hará el mismo el trabajo de actualizar la vista.

Comment: sii.. ya me los muestra pero cuando quiero mostrar otro diferente lo agrega junto con el que estaba ya

Comment: solo limpia el datagrid cada vez que le regreses datos del formulario B al A